# Can't get python to import nba_py that's in a different folder

Tags: python, module, python-import

I am using Python2.7 and Google App Engine for this project. I am a huge NBA fan and I want to use [nba_py](https://github.com/seemethere/nba_py)  api to retrieve additional information to be display on my website but can't seem to import it correctly. I am trying to import it inside my blogfront.py but when I refresh the browser I get an error. Here's my directory structure.

```
multi-user-blog
      - libraries
            - nba_py
                 -nba_py
                     - __init__.py
      - handlers
           -blogfront.py
           - __init__.py
      - mainblog.py
```

Here's my blogfront.py

```
from bloghandler import BlogHandler
from models.post import Post

from libraries.nba_py import nba_py


# Render Home Page
class BlogFront(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        # type: () -> object
        posts = Post.all().order('-created')
        title = "Blog/Scores"
        standing = get_standing()
        self.render('front.html', posts=posts, title=title)


    def get_standing():
        scoreboard = nba_py.Scoreboard()
        print scoreboard.west_conf_standings_by_day()
```

Here's my mainblog.py

```
import sys
import os
import re
import random
import hashlib
import hmac
import webapp2
import jinja2
import time


from handlers.bloghandler import BlogHandler
from handlers.blogfront import BlogFront
from handlers.deletecomment import DeleteComment
from handlers.deletepost import DeletePost
from handlers.likepost import Likes
from handlers.login import Login
from handlers.logout import Logout
from handlers.addcomment import AddComment
from handlers.newpost import NewPost
from handlers.postpage import PostPage
from handlers.signup import Signup
from handlers.signup import Register
from handlers.editcomment import EditComment
from handlers.editpost import EditPost


from models.comment import Comment
from models.user import User
from models.post import Post

from helpers import *

from string import letters
from google.appengine.ext import db


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', BlogFront),
                               ('/blog/?', BlogFront),
                               ('/postpage/([0-9]+)', PostPage),
                               ('/edit/([0-9]+)', EditPost),
                               ('/delete/([0-9]+)', DeletePost),
                               ('/addcomment/([0-9]+)', AddComment),
                               ('/blog/([0-9]+)/editcomment/([0-9]+)',
                                EditComment),
                               ('/blog/([0-9]+)/deletecomment/([0-9]+)',
                                DeleteComment),
                               ('/blog/like/([0-9]+)', Likes),
                               ('/blog/newpost', NewPost),
                               ('/signup', Register),
                               ('/login', Login),
                               ('/logout', Logout),
                               ],
                              debug=True)
```

The error is: ImportError: No module named libraries.nba_py

Comment: Is the same import working in `mainblog.py` as opposed to `blogfront.py`?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install `nba_py`?

If you install it with pip, you can just do `import nba_py`.
There is no need for your `libraries` structure.

Comment: Yeah that's how I installed it with pip install nba_py. I tried that, but it gave me an error saying ImportError: No module named nba_py

Comment: You have to import it as: `import nba_py` not `from libraries...`. You can get rid of your libraries directory at all, if `nba_py` is its only content.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did and it still say: No module named nba_py

Comment: I have just tested it. `pip install nba_py`. After that i could import it in the python interpreter with `import nba_py`. Are you sure you have installed it on the Google server?

Comment: I looked at the Google app engine docs. They need a special treatment for installing 3rd party packages. Please read the information at [Google app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting a connection error now: multi-user-blog/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', HTTPException('Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard?GameDate=02%2F21%2F2018&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0',))

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `__init__.py` at every step in the directory chain? That always gets me

```
multi-user-blog
      - libraries
            - __init__.py       <-------
            - nba_py
                 - __init__.py  <-------
                 -nba_py
                     - __init__.py
```

Comment: I just added them to libraries and nba_py and now I got: /multi-user-blog/libraries/nba_py/nba_py/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests import get
ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: good! it worked, now you have a dependency error. You may want to delete `libraries/nba_py` and install it into `libraries` with pip: `pip install -t libraries nba_py`.  (do this from the `multi-user-blog` dir). Option 2 is to chance dependencies manually, and copy paste python-requests into `libraries` yourself, but then there might be more dependencies to chase

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting a connection error now: multi-user-blog/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', HTTPException('Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard?GameDate=02%2F21%2F2018&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0',))

Comment: are you getting that error only on your localhost? or also when deployed? This may only be a problem on your localhost. I had to do the whole `requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()` thing to get outbound https requests to work https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_http_request

Comment: Sorry had to study for 3 midterms. I haven't tried deploying the new changes. What steps should I take first?

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, it's not clear whether you've followed the advice in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27 and installed `nba_py` into your project using using `pip install -t`, and also added an `appengine_config.py` to do a `vendor.add()`. Without those steps, your app will be sad.

Also, since `nba_py` wants to use pandas, you'll want to also `pip install -t` it, and since pandas wants numpy, you'll need the following in your `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting a connection error now: multi-user-blog/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', HTTPException('Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard?GameDate=02%2F21%2F2018&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0',))

Comment: Congratulations! You've passed the 'getting it installed' hurdle and are at the 'making it work' hurdle. I'd start a new question for the deadlines exceeded issue.